# Java, Netty, io.netty.util.ResourceLeakDetector reportTracedLeak при том что все зарелизено

Tags: java, netty

мой проект есть на гитхабе https://github.com/Xokyopo/myGIT/tree/master/Java/network_storage/network_storage_step_1
проблема в том что весь буфер что запрашиваю - релижу, но мне все равно выдает ошибку.
при том даже на стороне сервера, где он просто считывает и в ответ отправляет очень маленькие запросы.
написал небольшой класс что бы посмотреть как релизяться ссылки на объекты (ByteBuffRefCounter)
после закрытия всех соединений он выдал такое сообщение:

```
зарелизено
FrameEncoderDecoder write resultBuff :зарелизено =14316
FrameEncoderDecoder channelRead input :зарелизено =162714
ByteBufHandler channelRead input :зарелизено =14559
FrameEncoderDecoder write outBuff :зарелизено =14559
не зарелизено
```

т.е. все объекты были благополучно зарелизины, но ошибки он валит тоннами.
лог ошибки такой.
https://pastebin.com/TRUejM2L
буду рад вашей помощи с данной проблемой.

Comment: для запуска используются: сервер MyProtoServer, и много клиентов в потоках MultiProtocolClientsFileUploader. при запуски клиенты авторизируются и начинают передачу файлов одновременно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нужно запустить программу в JVM с опцией `-Dio.netty.leakDetection.level=advanced` или `-Dio.netty.leakDetection.level=paranoid`. Ещё неплохо было бы подключить log4j, чтобы ловить сообщения от Netty.

После того, как я запустил ваш проект с такой опцией JVM, я получил следующее:

```
Jul 05, 2020 12:01:32 PM io.netty.util.ResourceLeakDetector reportTracedLeak
SEVERE: LEAK: ByteBuf.release() was not called before it's garbage-collected. See https://netty.io/wiki/reference-counted-objects.html for more information.
Recent access records: 
#1:
    io.netty.buffer.AdvancedLeakAwareByteBuf.toString(AdvancedLeakAwareByteBuf.java:742)
    org.xokyopo.clientservercommon.protocol.MyByteBufUtil.getString(MyByteBufUtil.java:42)
    org.xokyopo.clientservercommon.protocol.executors.PFilePartServerExecutor.executeRequest(PFilePartServerExecutor.java:61)
    org.xokyopo.clientservercommon.protocol.executors.template.PExecutorAdapter.executeMessage(PExecutorAdapter.java:29)
    org.xokyopo.clientservercommon.protocol.handlers.ByteBufHandler.channelRead(ByteBufHandler.java:45)
    io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
    io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
    (и ещё много строк)
```

Посмотрев на эти методы, я нашёл проблему:

```
public static String getString(ByteBuf byteBuf) {
    return byteBuf.readBytes(byteBuf.readInt()).toString(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
}
```

`byteBuf.readBytes(byteBuf.readInt())` создаёт ByteBuf, который нигде не релизится.

После того, заменил метод на такой:

```
public static String getString(ByteBuf byteBuf) {
    ByteBuf b = byteBuf.readBytes(byteBuf.readInt());
    String result = b.toString(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    b.release();
    return result;
}
```

сообщения об утечках больше не появлялись. Поменял назад - они появились снова, так что проблема была именно в этом методе.

Comment: Благодарю, я бы сам никогда не подумал что тут ошибка.